# Internal error in the expression evaluator in ASP.net core web application while remote debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, remote-debugging

I have developed an ASP.Net core project and deployed it onto a production machine that runs IIS and its working fine. However, when I debug this asp.net core application using visual studio 2019 remote debugger, I am not able to view the variable values in a quick watch. It's showing the internal error in the expression evaluator. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition on my local system.

I have tried to use "Use the legacy c# and vb expression evaluators" 
option and "Use Compatibility mode". It has not worked. Any ideas?

[image: internal error in quick watch]

Comment: Please only include relevant tags (i.e. ones relevant to the question being asked).

Comment: Could you copy full exception text here?